Why we can't implement an ideal digital filter in the frequency domain and then anti-transform?
It is well known that a digital ideal low pass filter is not feasible since in frequency domain it's a rect function and in the time domain a sinc, which extends infinitely along the entire time axis and so the filter would have an infinite number of coefficients, basically requiring an infinite amount of time in order to process the input, since it would need an infinite number of samples for each processing step.
This is the most common answer that I used to find on the web but that doesn't convince me if I change the point of view for two reasons/questions that came into my mind:
1)There are IIR filters, which technically have infinite impulse responses and they are implementable obviously
2)Why is not possible to simply pick up the ideal DFT of a low pass filter (with a certain number of samples), then multiply it with the DFT of the input and finally antitrasform to the time domain obtaining so the output in the time domain?

This is a common newbie sorta question.  It's a good question.  When you inverse DFT the frequency response, you will get an impulse response that is as long as the DFT.  What you need is an impulse response that is as long as your allowed FIR length.


Why is not possible to simply pick up the ideal DFT of a low pass filter (with a certain number of samples), then multiply it with the DFT of the input and finally [inverse] transform to the time domain obtaining so the output in the time domain?

Okay, the Discrete Fourier Transform is a circular or periodic thingie.
When you multiply in one domain (say the frequency domain)...
$$Y[k]=H[k] \cdot X[k]$$
that causes convolution (the filtering operation) in the other domain (the time domain).
$$\begin{align}
y[n] &= x[n] \circledast h[n]   \\
 &= \sum\limits_{i=0}^{L-1} \tilde{x}[n-i] h[i] \\
\end{align}$$
Here, $L$ is the length of the FIR filter, the number of non-zero taps of the FIR filter and is much less than the size of the DFT, $L \ll N$.  The problem is that the convolution, $\circledast$, is circular, due to the use of the DFT.
$$ \tilde{x}[n+N] = \tilde{x}[n] \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Here, $\tilde{x}[n]$ is the periodic extension of the block of samples $x[n]$ that you sent to the DFT.
$$ \tilde{x}[n] = x[ (\!(n)\!)_N ] = x[n\bmod_N] \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, \ N \in \mathbb{Z}>0$$
where $ \qquad\qquad\qquad (\!(n)\!)_N  \triangleq n\bmod_N = n - N\left\lfloor \frac{n}{N} \right\rfloor  $
The notation $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ means the floor() function which is the largest integer that does not exceed the argument.
This means that the first $L-1$ samples of the output $y[n]$ are corrupted due to time aliasing in the circular convolution.  When $0 \le n \le L-2$, then $y[n]$ is corrupted because the impulse response $h[n]$ straddles the boundary of $\tilde{x}[n]$ between $\tilde{x}[-1]=\tilde{x}[N-1]$ and $\tilde{x}[0]$.  When $n=L-1$ is when the first uncorrupted value of $y[n]$ comes out.
Now, if you can guarantee that the last $L-1$ samples in $x[n]$ going into the DFT are zero, that will prevent contamination of wrapping around $n=0$ (the time aliasing), but there will be a sorta ramp up to $y[L-1]$ in the output.
So, your frequency response $H[k]$ can't be whatever you draw out to your heart's desire.  $H[k]$ must be the DFT of an FIR $h[n]$ that has zero samples $h[n]=0$ for all $L \le n \le N-1$.
So what you gotta do (let's say you're using MATLAB or whatever) is draw out the frequency response you want in a friggin' huge FFT.  I have done this for $N = 2^{20}$, an FFT of a megasample long.  Draw out your frequency response for the $\frac{N}2$ positive frequency points and reflect that for $H[N-k]=H[k]$.
Now inverse FFT.
Then window this thing to a decent length $L$ with a good window.  Like a Kaiser window.  Now all of your samples except $L$ samples are zero,
Now FFT back and you will see the approximation of what you drew and about the best you can do with an FIR of length $L$.

The problem with the sinc function is not that it is infinitely long. The problem is that it is infinitely non-causal, i.e., it extends infinitely towards negative times. All implementable IIR filters are obviously causal. Another problem with the sinc function is that it decays slowly, which causes the ideal lowpass filter to be unstable. This means that there are bounded input signals resulting in an unbounded response. This is something you want to avoid when implementing a system.
The idea of implementing the filter in the frequency domain doesn't solve the problem either. Of course, frequency domain implementations are used a lot, and they have clear advantages over time domain implementations for long filter lengths. But you don't get any closer to an ideal filter. You've mentioned the reason yourself by adding "(with a certain number of samples)" to your suggestion. That's exactly the problem. Of course you can guarantee a prescribed behavior on the DFT grid, but you have no control over what's happening between those grid points. I believe it's very instructive to try such an implementation yourself to see what's going on. For more information on this topic take a look at one of the most frequently viewed questions on this site Why is it a bad idea to filter by zeroing out FFT bins?.
